# Changing multiple array keys/names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, underscore.js

So basically I've an array called `arrayObj` with three objects. So I have `arrayObj[0]`, `arrayObj[1]` and `arrayObj[2]`. In those three objects I have the key name`["user"]` three times, obviously. I want to change those key names and made a function.

This is my function so far:

`function renameObjNames(){
    arrayObj[0].randomkeyname= arrayObj[0].user;
    delete arrayObj[0].user;
}`

This function does only change the first one. I tried something with the for-loop, but unfortunally I suck with those loops. Is there a way to dynamically change the index of arrayObj[?]. I want to change those three at once in a function.

Any additional help is always welcome. Sorry for my grammar if it is disturbing you. Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, this will help you.

```
function renameObjNames(){
    var tmpobj = arrayObj;
    for(var i=0,cnt=arrayObj.length;i<cnt;i++){
        arrayObj[i].randomkeyname= arrayObj[i].user;
        delete arrayObj[i].user;
    }
    arrayObj = tmpobj;
}
```

Comment: I also tried something like this and I tried your function. It does change the keynames, but only arrayObj[1] does have the data I first had insde the objects. http://puu.sh/geRu5/e26789c6b9.png

Comment: @dirtyeightt, can you add the object code here or to jsfiddle so we can take a look at what the problem might be.

Comment: @dirtyeightt, try my edited code and if it doesn't work please try to paste sample array/object here.

Comment: @SD. Check out the link: jsfiddle.net/syffvhq7/3.

Comment: @dirtyeightt please check edited code. I have tried it, works well.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I noticed it is working on JSFiddle. But when I try it, the first and last objects are undefined.

Comment: @dirtyeightt now it should work with above code change.